# R: Convert monthly data into daily data for panel data

Tags: r, panel

I have the following data:

[5 Products with a monthly rating from 2018-08 to 2018-12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffPDK.png)

Now with the help of R programming I would like to convert the monthly data into daily data and to have panel data.The monthly rating for each product will also be the rating for each day in the respective month.

So, that the new data will look like:

(with the first column being the product, the second column the date and the third column the rating)

```
A 2018-08-01 1
A 2018-08-02 1
A 2018-08-03 1
A 2018-08-04 1
... so on
A 2018-09-01 1
A 2018-09-02 1
...so on
A 2018-12-31 1
B 2018-08-01 3
B 2018-08-02 3
... so on
E 2018-12-31 3
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# example data
data <- tribble(
  ~Product, ~`Product Rating 2018-08`, ~`Product Rating 2018-10`,
  "A", 1, 1,
  "B", 3, 3,
)

data2 <-
  data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Product) %>%
  mutate(
    name = name %>% str_extract("[0-9-]+$") %>% paste0("-01") %>% as.Date()
  )

seq(as.Date("2018-08-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "days") %>%
  tibble(date = .) %>%
  # left join on year and month
  expand_grid(data2) %>%
  filter(month(date) == month(name) & year(date) == year(name)) %>%
  select(Product, date, value)
#> # A tibble: 124 × 3
#>    Product date       value
#>    <chr>   <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 A       2018-08-01     1
#>  2 B       2018-08-01     3
#>  3 A       2018-08-02     1
#>  4 B       2018-08-02     3
#>  5 A       2018-08-03     1
#>  6 B       2018-08-03     3
#>  7 A       2018-08-04     1
#>  8 B       2018-08-04     3
#>  9 A       2018-08-05     1
#> 10 B       2018-08-05     3
#> # … with 114 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! How could you change the order of the output so that first only Product A is listed from 2018-08-01 to 2018-12-31 with the respective value, and then afterward Product B? Right now it is always changing between product A and B.

Comment: Put `%>% arrange(Product, date)` at the end

Comment: In case you have yearly data instead of monthly data and you would like to convert this data into daily data, how do we need to adjust the code?

Comment: Just remove `month(date) == month(name)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! But then data2 <-
  data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Product) %>%
  mutate(
    name = name %>% str_extract("[0-9-]+$") %>% paste0("-01") %>% as.Date()
  ) just adds -01 and the months are not included yet. How could you include it?

Comment: Ah, use `paste0("01-01")`  instead. this pretends to use the first of January instead of the first of any month

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help.